# "decorated" keyword not implemented in micropython?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-decorators, micropython

I'm trying to use the aiomqtt module ([https://github.com/sbtinstruments/aiomqtt]) in a micropython program on an ESP32-S3 system, but I get a syntax error on this statement in aiomqtt's client.py file:

```
async def decorated(self: ClientT, /, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
```

I assume this is because "decorated" is not implemented in micropython, but I'm a bit unclear on Python decorators and hence not sure if that's the real issue. I would appreciate if someone more knowledgeable would comment.

I'm running micropython v1.20.0 (the latest release) and the same code runs fine on python 3.11.0 on my Mac. Is there a workaround that avoids use of "decorated"?

Comment: What's the exact error you get? `decorated` doesn't need to be implemented, it's just an arbitrary function name, and you're showing us where it is being defined.

Comment: I'd rather guess micropython either doesn't support `async`, type annotations or `/`…?!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 ```File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "weatherFeather.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "/lib/aiomqtt/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/lib/aiomqtt/client.py", line 115
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: micropython definitely supports async. I use async functions all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positional-only argument syntax (`/`) was [introduced in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters). MicroPython 1.20 [does not support it](https://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.20.0/differences/python_38.html).

Comment: Thanks @deceze! That's the problem and it's easy for me to work around.